# Showing specific part of an image in a limited space?

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, jscrollpane

I have a frame of 100x100 and an image of 400x400, I have a layered pane on the entire frame and the image inside the layered pane. As you can notice the image is bigger than the frame so only a part of the image i.e. the top-left part of the image will be shown. Suppose there is a man in the image at X=32 and y=40 and width = 10 and height = 10 (basically a rectangle) w.r.t. the frame.

### Questions

1. the image is 400x400 right? That means at runtime I can only see 100x100 part of the image and the part of the image that has been shown is the top-left part right? But suppose I want to show a building that is situated at 350x350 w.r.t. the image, then how do I do it (since it is located in the bottom part of the image so it wont be shown)?
2. suppose the first question is solved, then assume there is a building at 350x350 with width = 20 and height = 20 w.r.t the 'frame'. Now when at runtime I show the image (now the bottom part of the image is visible, assuming question 1 is solved) the co-ordinates of the building w.r.t. frame should not change i.e. they should remain 350x350 w.r.t. the frame.

Comment: I don't clearly understand question 2. Do you mean to ask that since you're at point[350,350] (let's call this point X) that you want X to be at [350,350] for your calculations? If it's just for calculation, I think you ought to consider finding the where the image's "root" is (should be [-350,-350]) and then do relative calculation. Not sure if I understand this perfectly so please clarify.

Comment: Answer not acceptable? Let me know what other information you need.

Answer (score 3):

Point 1) I'm guessing you're adding the image in a `JPanel` and then into the `JFrame` or the image into a `JPanel` which goes into a `JScrollPane` which finally lands inside the `JFrame`. `JPanel`s and `JScrollPane`s both support programmatic scrolling through the use of [#scrollRectToVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).

Here's a (kind of) working sample of the scrollRectToVisible

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 11000));
SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
panel2.setLayout(layout);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    JLabel textField = new JLabel();
    textField.setText("textfield number " + i);
    textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 100));
    layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, textField, i * 110, SpringLayout.NORTH, panel2);

    panel2.add(textField);
}
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel2, ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 500));

panel2.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(0, 800, 150, 100));

panel.add(scrollPane);
```

Add the panel variable to a JFrame and you're good to run this code. Also, please note that this is meant to be sample code, not the actual way code should be written to add components to panels :P

Point 2) I still don't fully understand this query so I'll give you an answer in 2 parts.
a) I don't see why relative calculations matter? Can you try the sample I provided and see if it does what it needs to? If not, read option b
b) the `Rectangle` object has a `setLocation(int, int)` (Reference: [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#setLocation%28int,%20int%29)) that you should play around with. I can't give you a more accurate answer or a code sample since I don't full understand what you're trying to do and I don't have a code sample that I can play with.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion but could you give me an example code (pseudo code is fine).

Comment: Added sample code as requested and a possible answer to query 2.

Comment: teeth.gritting ... do.not.call.setXXSize **ever**

Comment: @kleopatra it's meant to be sample code just to demonstrate how the scrollRectToVisible() works. :( Fine.. I'll not do it in samples either :(